# Get Data between 2 dates C# in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get data between two dates, in my SQL code I use columns with datatype `datetime` in order to save the actions of a user (pressing button).

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE Actions_Data
(
    [id] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Auto] datetime NULL,
    [Manual] datetime NULL,
    [Buttons_Off] datetime NULL,
    [start_pump1] datetime NULL,
    [stop_pump1] datetime NULL,
)
```

My C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  Actions_Data WHERE Auto BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy- MM- dd HH: mm:ss") + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy- MM- dd HH: mm:ss") + "'", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlDa.Fill(ds, "Actions_Data");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Actions_Data"];
con.Close();
```

In this way I can get the data of only one column named Auto. Do you know how can I get all the data of my table? (I tried `*` in the position of Auto but it doesn't work) Thank you in advance!

My purpose is the ability to search all the data that I have in a datagridview between two dates

I followed this video: https://youtu.be/2hJGolhxFJo

Comment: Is `Auto` a DATETIME column?

Comment: yes , it represents the datetime i pressed the button Auto

Comment: Dates are binary values, they have no format. Use parameterized queries with `DateTime` or `DateOnly` values. Right now your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and culture-specific conversion errors. Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'); DROP TABLE Student;--` in a text field that's concatenated to a query string

Comment: @sakis what's the definition of the table? `SELECT *` *does* return all columns. If you don't see all of them, either there aren't any or some *other* code doesn't display all of them. `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't display data, it's only used to load results into DataTables. Did you check the contents of the DataTable? How do you display the results?

Comment: Yikes. This technique is scary-vulnerable to injection issues.

Comment: In addition to the terrible SQL injection issue you have, you will likely find that listing the columns to select is a better idea than `SELECT *`.  As your system undergoes maintenance, new columns get added to the tables, not always in the same order in different environments.  Using `SELECT *` can really mess things up

Comment: What data are you trying to get between two dates?  Is each column a separate button?  Do all of them get updated at the same time?  There might be an issue with your table design.

Comment: every column represents a separate button

Comment: What are your datePicker dates based on?  When you use `*`, you get data for all columns, not just `Auto`.  Is this what you want?

Comment: no iam getting error with *

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Parameterized queries**. *USE THEM.*

```
using var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
using var da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
SELECT * 
FROM Actions_Data 
WHERE Auto >= @StartDate AND Auto < @EndDate", con);

da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

Separately, this **WILL** return data for all the columns. If you don't see other columns, look at the code the reads and displays the results, because I promise you this query will grab all of them from the table. And as others have said, you're generally better off listing the column names you need than using the `*` wildcard.

---

Based on the edits, the problem is the definition of the `dataGridView1` control. There's only one column defined for the control. That's where you need to make the change.  Also, that video is **NOT GOOD**. It's demonstrating a number of a poor practices, not the least of which is using string concatenation to put the data into the query instead of parameters.

Comment: `*` guarantees all columns will be returned though, which means either there are no other columns, or the rest of the code isn't displaying them. Perhaps the grid the DataTable binds to only shows one column

Comment: i don't know what's the problem , after where in my code i tried * but unfortunately no result

Comment: `after WHERE`  What? It's part of the SELECT list, which is **before** WHERE.

Comment: this is the question , what should i write after where in order to include all my columns not only Auto column

Comment: @sakis NOTHING. It goes between `SELECT` and `FROM`, and you're already done it. **The problem is not in the query**, it's in a completely different part of the application.

Comment: What if your _Action_data_ table'd looks like `([id] int, [when] datetime, [what] int)` and you'd assign a certain value for each pressed button in `[what]`, ex. 1:Auto, 2:Manual, 4:Buttons_off, 8:Start_pump1...?